# exec: python2: not found after running gcloud init on Mac

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have just replaced my old Mac with M1 Mac and something went wrong with Python after the data transfer.

I am trying to run Big Query queries on Jupyter Notebook. After downloading the the google-cloud-sdk folder, I am running the command gcloud init to start the setup and login using the credentials. Something that used to work smoothly before.

Now, every time I run the command, this shows up in my terminal:

```
/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: line 181: exec: python2: not found
```

I am using Monterey v12.5.1, z shell. Any ideas how do I solve this?

Comment: I don't think they install Python 2 any more.  Just Python 3.  You should be able to get Python 2 through HomeBrew.  Are you using that?

Comment: I do not use HomeBrew and I also do not understand why would I need Python 2 in this case. I have Python 3.8.2 installed (shows after running python -V in terminal).

Comment: The `gcloud` command you have needs Python 2.  You need to upgrade to version 274.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113281/is-there-any-way-to-use-gcloud-with-python3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error after upgrading my Mac from macOS 10.15 (Catalina) to macOS 13 (Ventura). Adding this to your environment should solve the problem:

```bash
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

I also reinstalled `gcloud` using the Mac instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#mac. But I'm not sure this was necessary, so I suggest you just try setting `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` first.